# Calculating field from three conditional statements

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I am working on a road dataset and would like to calculate a field(speed) using three conditional statements from two fields:

1. formOfWay: with value, Dual carriageway etc.
2. routeHierarchy: with values A Road, A Road Primary etc.

My aim is to return a speed value of 65 where formOfWay is Dual Carriageway AND Route Hierarchy is either A Road or A Road Primary.

Using the code provided in a similar question asked, I have tried the code below in ArcGIS Field Calculator, but haven’t been unsuccessful. The error message returned point to a syntax error in line 2 and I suspect this should be the part of the code having the two `‘routeHierarchy’` values (A Road and A Road Primary).
 The code works with one coded value for routeHierarchy but returns an error when the second value is added.

```
def ifBlock(routeHierarchy, formOfWay):
    if routeHierarchy == ['A Road','A Road Primary'] and formOfWay == 'Dual Carriageway':
        return 65
    else:
        return 30
```

Please, can someone point out the correction I can apply to make this work?

Comment: did you try `if routeHierarchy in ['A Road','A Road Primary']`?

Comment: Hi Taras, thank you for your suggestion.I have tried the 'in' statement but it didn't work. Instead I got the value of 30 (as with the else statement) for all the rows in the speed field.

Comment: Having tried Ian's second code, your suggestion would have worked with a ( ) bracket instead of [ ].

Comment: that is true...sorry for misleading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need either:

```
def ifBlock(routeHierarchy, formOfWay):
    if (routeHierarchy == 'A Road' or routeHierarchy == 'A Road Primary') and formOfWay == 'Dual Carriageway':
        return 65
    else:
        return 30
```

or

```
def ifBlock(routeHierarchy, formOfWay):
    if routeHierarchy in ('A Road','A Road Primary') and formOfWay == 'Dual Carriageway':
        return 65
    else:
        return 30
```

Comment: Many thank Ian Turton, both code worked. I only changed the one equal to sign before 'A Road Primary' to a double equals.